# Woocommerce : payments plugin activation : plugins listing erased

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment

I have an issue with a woocommerce payment-gateway plugin I've developped.

I have 4 plugins available in this section :

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout
```

[image]

---

And I have my plugin listed as deactivated in WP plugins here :

```
/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s
```

[image]

---

When I activate my plugin (**JC Paygate**), on that page, when I refresh the 
woocommerce payments section, all the 4 plugins are removed and only my plugin appears there.

[image]

---

All previous 4 plugins are now as-erased. I don't have a clue how to avoid it.
I just want my plugin to be the 5th available payments plugin in woocommerce.

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from my side.

--------- Right way was -----------

```
add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_coinify_add_gateway'); 

function woocommerce_coinify_add_gateway( $gateways) 
{
    $gateways[] = 'WC_Gateway_MYWCPLUGIN';
    return $gateways;
}
```

On my side, I was doing in **woocomerce_coinify_add_gateway**

```
function woocommerce_coinify_add_gateway( $gateways) 
{
    return [ 'WC_Gateway_MYWCPLUGIN' ];
}
```

So instead of adding my gateway to other gateways, the list was only containing one entry (my plugin), since the array was completely replaced instead of just entry-added.